# Find and convert to upper and replace special characters with specific values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have data like  below in one of the column

```
hdf---country-state-dist---comma
comma---nav-bs-takeoff
A_without - nasa general cn
```

But my desired output should be like below

```
HDF - Country - State - Dist - Comma
comma - Nav Bs Takeoff
Without - Nasa General Cn
```

Can somebody to help how to get my desired output.

Comment: Thanks Dale for your quick reply. select *,REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(column,'---',' - '),'- comma','- comma'),'V_','') from Reporting. But not sure how to replace lower case to upper case before first ocurrence of blank.

Comment: [edit] the complete query (ideally with sample data) into your question.

Comment: That kind of upper case conversion is almost impossible in T-SQL. T-SQL is not geared for that sort of thing. I suggest a CLR function written in .NET which allows you more control.

Comment: Agree that this should be done in .NET. Looks mostly like a regex problem to me. Not sure what the rule is for `A_without` though